# Is there a way to count occurences of a word until another word shows in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

At the moment my spread sheet has a column that says Win or Lose, I want to be able to count how many times Win shows up before Lose does (in this case it should show 6, 2, 2, 2)

[image: Screenshot of Sheet]

Comment: I feel like this belongs on [Web Apps SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
=flatten(index(len(split(join(,left(A:A)),"L"))))
```

[image]

Take the first letter, join everything in one cell, split by L and return the length.

This will work as long as you don't have 50k+ entries.